# ssh: connect to host <host name/ip> port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, networking, openssh

When attempting to connect to the tryhackme provided IP address we get port 22: connection timed out even while our ssh server is active

When I attempt to

> ssh -vvv tryhackme@10.10.72.152

I get the below result while using verbosity 3 -vvv

```
OpenSSH_9.0p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu7.1, OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.10.72.152 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/kali/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/kali/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.72.152 [10.10.72.152] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address 10.10.72.152 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.10.72.152 port 22: Connection timed out
```

We have verified the ssh server is active w/

> sudo systemctl status ssh

```
ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d
             └─00-socket.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-01-06 01:45:26 PST; 58min ago
TriggeredBy: ● ssh.socket
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 824 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 2281)
     Memory: 1.6M
        CPU: 17ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─824 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

Jan 06 01:45:26 ubuntu-22 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jan 06 01:45:26 ubuntu-22 sshd[824]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jan 06 01:45:26 ubuntu-22 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

Then, when we check our LISTENING ports, we find that ::22 is (not sure the proper term yet for this) but configured to 1/init instead of something like 1823/sshd. Below is the following

> sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      587/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      804/cupsd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      587/systemd-resolve 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      804/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
```

So far we have used the below resources, but now I have not found anything further to assist, and kinda stuck. If anybody could provide further assistance that would be fantastic!:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-check-open-ports-in-linux-using-the-cli/

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-openssh-server/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172188/ssh-server-connect-to-host-xxx-port-22-connection-timed-out-on-linux-ubuntu

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057705/how-to-resolve-port-22-connection-timeout

tryhackme ip for reassurance:
[image: Tryhackme machine ip]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please? Are you actually connected to this machine? If you cannot ssh into it, how did you run `sudo systemctl status ssh`? And, if you are somehow connected to the machine, what is the output of `sudo systemctl status sshd`? That's the one you want, not `ssh`.

Comment: @terdon While most distributions might use `sshd.service` as the service name of the SSH server, Debian and related distributions do use `ssh.service` for historical reasons.

Comment: Ah, thanks @telcoM, I haven't used a Debian-based system in a few years so I seem to have forgotten.

Comment: Edit question to tell us: What is the physical connection (ethernet, virtual machine, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Your `ubuntu-22` system is configured to start `sshd` only when needed, using systemd *socket activation*. In other words, when no SSH connection attempts have yet been received, the `ssh.service` will not be started yet: there will be only `ssh.socket`, which is managed by PID #1/`init` (which is actually `systemd` in your case).

When the first SSH connection attempt arrives to port TCP/22, `ssh.socket` automatically triggers `ssh.service` to start up and passes the incoming connection to the service. This is why you see

```
TriggeredBy: ● ssh.socket
```

in `systemctl status ssh` output.

Since the SSH service was successfully activated by connection attempts, that means packets from your client system can probably reach the `10.10.72.152` system. But the `Connection timed out` error indicates that *no answer of any kind was received*.

This might suggest that you have a firewall configuration problem somewhere: a firewall is set to allow incoming packets to TCP/22 to 10.10.72.152, but *the responses are not allowed back out* and are dropped by the firewall.

It might be an overly defensively configured firewall on your client system, a software firewall on the tryhackme virtual machine, or even separately-configurable firewall rules on the cloud service you're using to run your tryhackme.

It might be helpful to run `sudo traceroute -T -p 22 10.10.72.152` to see how far a TCP-based traceroute can get when trying to reach the SSH port on the tryhackme server. If you get responses only from your local host, it's probably your local software firewall; if you get all the way to the router of the tryhackme server, it might be the software firewall on the tryhackme VM; if the responses stop somewhere in between (and there *are* multiple in-between steps) then it might be the cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

`:::22` shows that is is listening on IPv6, port 22. I don't see it listening on IPv4.

You also need to configure the firewall (if on).